# Peer to peer data replication feature in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there any Peer to peer data replication feature available for PostgreSQL ? similar one available for MS SQLServer 2019

Comment: You can't expect PostgreSQL experts to know all features of SQL Server. What exactly is "peer to peer replication"? What problem are you trying to solve with that? Maybe if you there is  a concept in Postgres that will achieve that.

Answer (score -2):

No this concept of replication does not exists in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL does not have all the data replication features that MS do (merge, snapshot, peer to peer...)

Just have a look on one my my paper that speaks about :
[PostgreSQL vs. SQL Server (MSSQL) – part 3 – Very Extremely Detailed Comparison](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/)

Especially § "*What are the replication differences between PostgreSQL and SQL Server? Compare replication in PostgreSQL vs. MSSQL*"

Comment: A word of warning, the *paper* quoted in the answer is a bizarre collection of untrue information.

Comment: @klin saying that this paper is untrue without any comment of what is untrue... is'nt it fake news ???

Comment: There are too many errors in the article to be listed in a short commentary. Not all of them are yours, some of them were copied from the article you criticized, eg [UUID type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html). Aside from this kind of distortion, you are wrong on many grounds. You are lying about four isolation levels in Postgres, optimistic/pessimistic locking, and binary backups, among other things. You have no idea how Postgres replication works or how Postgres partitioned tables are defined. I would say you know Postgres well, but only by hearsay.